# Trying to compile and run c++ code with java code

Tags: java, c++, batch-file

I was trying to compile and run a c++ program from a java program, I made a .bat file having compilation and execution command, The code for making .bat file works fine, but code to open the .bat file doesn't work. It says "g++  is not recognized as an internal/external command", but if I open .bat file manually, it works fine. please help me with the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Batch
{
    FileOutputStream fos;
    DataOutputStream dos;

    public Batch()
    {
    }

    public void createBat() throws Exception
    {
        File file=new File("M:\\AV\\compile_Execute.bat"); 
        fos=new FileOutputStream(file);
        dos=new DataOutputStream(fos);
        dos.writeBytes("@echo off");
        dos.writeBytes("\n");
        dos.writeBytes("g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 & main.exe");
        fos.close();
    }

    public void executeBat() throws Exception
    {
        String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/C", "Start", "M:\\AV\\compile_execute.bat"};

        Process p =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    }
}
```

Comment: `g++` is not in you path.

Comment: but when i open this .bat file, it does generate the main.exe file.

Comment: open `cmd` and type `where /r c:\ g++` and wait for it to print output to screen. Let me know what that output is.

Comment: c:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe
c:\msys64\usr\share\bash-completion\completions\g++                                                   this is the output.

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is that you messed up with the path, because the file is located in another drive, you cannot just use the path or go back a folder using ".."

1. Firstly, go to the biggest directory

   ```
   cd "C:\"
   ```
2. Then, change drive

   ```
   M:
   ```

   *Note that to change directoy you must be in the drive biggest folder and that to change drives, you must use the format `letter:`*

   *These two steps can be simplified to `cd D:`*
3. Next:

   ```
    cd "M:\\AV\\"
   ```
4. Finally:

   ```
    compile_execute.bat
   ```

Merging it, I would use this instead of just a path: `cd /D M:\\AV\\ compile_execute.bat`

I suggest reading about [MS-DOS](https://www.computerhope.com/cmd.htm).

Thanks for the comment related to not being able to change directory to a file.